# Lines and polygons intersection with tolerance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, intersection, tolerance

I have a layer with polygons and a layer with polylines.

I am looking for the list of polygons crossed by the polylines.

Just here it's relatively simple: intersection function.

That said, the layout of the line is not perfect, so I would like to exclude polygon for which the line only touches the polygon contour or does not fit more than 1m into the polygon.

Comment: have you been able to make it work?

Comment: unfortunately, the result of the query does not take into account the tolerance. I have the same result as with a simple intersection. On the other hand, I found another solution which consisted in applying beforehand a negative buffer zone of 1m on the polygons

Answer (score 6):

I'd go for SQL (QGIS natively supports the [*SpatiaLite 4.3.0*](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html) dialect for any layer query) and check for the spatial relation with the *negative buffered* polygons:

- `QGIS | DB Manager`

  - connect to `Virtual Layers` (double-click) in the left panel (make sure your layers are loaded in the project)
  - open the `SQL Window` (second icon to the left)

    - in the top panel, run (`Execute`)

      ```
      SELECT a.<id>,
             group_concat(b.<id>) AS its_lines,
             a.geometry 
      FROM <polygon_layer> AS a
      JOIN <line_layer> AS b
        ON ST_Relate(ST_Buffer(a.geometry, -1), b.geometry, 'T********')
      GROUP BY a.id;
      ```
    - load the produced table as a layer to the project by ticking the `Load as new layer` checkbox and fill in the fields

The above query will return a table with all polygon `<id>`s (paste the actual id field name here), their `geometries` and a concatenated string of line `<id>`s (same here) that *intersect*, but not *touch*, the negative buffered polygons of your layer.

**Important:**
Since you asked for meters, I put -1 in `ST_Buffer`. However, the function will treat the passed number in CRS units; here, this implies **that you are working with a CRS whose units *are* in *meter***! If you are working in LatLon, e.g. EPSG:4326, the parameter in `ST_Buffer` will be treated as *degrees*...and thus makes no sense. In that case, a transformation into an appropriate projection is necessary; you can do that with
`... ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(a.geometry, <srid_of_metric_CRS>), -1) ...`

Comment: Unfortunately, the result of the query does not take into account the tolerance. I have the same result as with a simple intersection. On the other hand, I found another solution which consisted in applying beforehand a negative buffer zone of 1m on the polygons

Comment: @tdeleye that is *exactly* what this query does...

Answer (score 5):

Meanwhile ([since QGIS 3.16](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core) with the new [`overlay_crosses`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=overlay_intersects#overlay-crosses) function) you can use QGIS expressions to automatically calculate what you want. The expression to use on the lines layer and referring to the polygon layer (replace `polygon` with the name of your polygon layer) looks like this - see below for an explanation. You can use this expression with field calculator. If you create a virtual field, the value will update automatically if you change the geometries of the lines or polygons or add new features - quite handy! You might also use the expression for visual purposes only when pasting it as a label (as done in the screenshot below).

```
array_length (
    array_remove_all( 
        array_foreach (
            overlay_crosses( 
                'polygon', 
                $geometry
            ),
            if (
                length (
                    intersection( 
                        $geometry ,
                        @element
                    )
                )<5,
                0,
                1
            )
        ), 
        0
    )
)
```

*Screenshot: the line is labeled with the expression from above. As you see, some intersections are not counted (red circles) because the line is too short (`<5`). As well, if a line intersects more than once the same polygon (red arrows), it is counted just once:*
[image]

1. `overlay_crosses('polygon', $geometry)` gets all the geometries from the layer `polygon` - thus applied on the line-layer, you access all the polygons, **collected in an array**.
2. `array_foreach ()`: for each element of the array (=for each polygon), perform an operation.
3. The operation to perform: A) intersect the current feature (line) with each element from the array (in the `array_foreach` clause, refer to it with `@element`); B) get the length of this intersecting line with `length ()`; C) inside an `if()`-clause: if this length is smaller than 5 (or every value you define here on line 15), return `0`, otherwise `1`.
4. From the resulting array, remove all `0` values with `array_remove_all( )`, that means: all lines that are shorter than 5. For each polygon your line crosses for 5 or more meters, you get a value of `1` in the array - thus if the line crosses 3 polygons for more than 5 meters and 2 polygons for just 1 or 2 meters, the result will be: `[1,1,1]`.
5. Return the number of remaining elements in the array with `array_length ()`. In the example from step 4, the result would be: `3`.